# Network Sharing Dies Constantly followup

Tags: macos, network, high-sierra, sharing

We have the same situation as in this post - [Network Sharing Dies Constantly](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/310815/network-sharing-dies-constantly) 
The server stops publishing its shares to the network and none of the 10.13 and 10.14 Mac clients can access the shares anymore. It's happening on a Mac Pro 2010 running 10.13.6 with all the latest patches. The symptoms are identical with the exception that it happens weekly, not hourly.  Apple tech support was less than helpful.  Glorfindel, were you able to resolve the problem or did your touch script provide a workaround? We are planning on migrating to 10.14 when the new Mac Pro is available but any assistance or insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Check if something on your network is Blocking mDNS, Bounjour or ZeroConf protocols

Comment: SMB over TCP/IP is open - From port scan "Open TCP Port: 445   microsoft-ds"